# N-Channel MOSFET LED driver issue with PMV13XNEAR

Tags: mosfet, led

I am testing the below which should be fairly simple unless I am missing out on something.

[image: Schematic]

Q1 is a  [PMV13XNEAR](https://www.nexperia.com/products/mosfets/small-signal-mosfets/PMV13XNEA.html). LED_CONTROL is being switched on/off by a PIC microcontroller and I can confirm that it is working since at Q1-Pin 1 I measure 0 V and 4.9 V on different states.

However Q1-pin 3 always remains at 0 V. Port LED has an LED with a 4.7 kΩ resistor connected to 9 V. In fact the LED is always on.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Your schematics looks like having no error. How did you know that the LED is always on? Did you make the prototype?

Comment: @JLCPCBEngineer Yes I have a PCB based on this schematic.

Comment: Please check if the source and drain pins of Q1 are reverted.

Comment: Some footprints made by third-party contributors have bugs. So check the official datasheet of Q1 and if source/drain pins are routed correctly.

Comment: @JLCPCBEngineer Checked and confirmed this multiple times.

Comment: Could you share the whole schematics and Geber so that I can check in detail?

Comment: If you disconnect LED_CONTROL from MCU or make it's pin in Hi-Z state (input without pull-up, "floating"), i.e. when it's just always pulled to a ground, the LED are still on?

Comment: @NStorm Just tested this but it did not work as well

Comment: @LukeGalea if you mean that LED was on too in that case that could mean only 3 things: 1) your transistor are faulty/counterfeit; 2) you've connected it wrong (yet you've told you've double checked that); 3) current has other path to a ground - check you PCB.

Comment: @NStorm thanks! Will check again tomorrow.

Comment: You have a mistook on the gate drive, you are driving the MOSFET with a voltage divider. Place the pull down resistor 0n the processor port pin. This will increase the gate voltage by a few tenths, important with MOSFETs.

Comment: @Gil Vth is 1.3V and I am driving it at 4.9V however...

Comment: @Gil if low gate voltage was the case the LED would never turned on as this are N-ch FET. Instead it's always on according to the description.

Answer (score 2):

The circuit looks like it works on paper.
You’ve measured the gate voltages and they seem correct.
You say the mosfet is wired correctly.

So what does that tell us?
The mosfet may have failed.
There is a short circuit on the pcb, maybe due to soldering.

Lift pin 3 of the mosfet and test. If the led is still lit, the problem isn’t the mosfet. Look elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly funny/ashamed to state this but the LED pin was shorted to Ground only on the PCB that I tested. The other PCBs are fine. Just my luck ‍♂️ thank you for your help. It's working now!